# Client code is not receiving a published model

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have followed the directory format in the parties examples.  The only modifications I have made to the project is to run:

```
mrt remove autopublish.
```

**/model.coffee**

```
Goals = new Meteor.Collection("goals")

Goals.allow
  insert: (userId, goal) -> true
  update: (userId, goal, fields, modifier) -> true
  remove: (userId, goal) -> true
```

**/server/server.coffee**

```
Meteor.publish "goals", ->
  return Goals.find({})
```

**/client/main.coffee**

```
Meteor.subscribe "goals"

Template.main.goals = ->
  Goals.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}})
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Goals is not defined
```

Strangely, if I add "Goals = new Meteor.Collection("goals")" to the top of the client script, I get this error:

```
There is already a collection named 'goals'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `model.coffee` file, prefix your `Goal` variable with the `@` symbol:

```
@Goals = new Meteor.Collection("goals")
```

This is the way to define a global var in coffeescript. Actually `@` compile to `this.` and in the top scope `this` is the window object, the same for all client side files.

Comment: I also found that I had to put the models.coffee file in a lib directory so that it was loaded before the server and client folders.